# How to draw lotus in sacred geometry

Tags: drawing

Could someone explain how one draws the lotus symbol found in sacred geometry EG the around the chakra symbols found in Hinduism.

Is there a process as with the seed of life?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. You should post an example of the image you're referring to as me and probably other people do not know which image you're are talking about. You should also mention which program you will want to accomplish this in. Unless it doesn't matter. What have you tried to make this symbol?

Comment: Do you mean this kind of stylized petals? If so, as @AndrewH suggested, could you please add an image to the question? http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/lotus-seven-chakras-esoteric-symbols-35605643.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure the exact type of image you are trying to replicate but the process will generally be the same. A lot of these images use a rotation tool to rotate an object from a center point.

**The following was done in Illustrator** but can be done in other vector software programs.

Start by creating your circle by using the eclipse tool (L). You can hold shift to create a perfect circle.

Then create half of the pedal using the pen tool (P).

[image]

Copy the half pedal and paste. Reflect the second pedal (object - transform - reflect) and join the 2 pedals with the pathfinder (Window -> Pathfinder). I then rotated the pedal to one of the sides (object - transform - rotate).

[image: flower pedal]

Select the pedal, press r on the keyboard to select the Rotate Tool from your toolbar.

While holding Option down click on the center of the circle you made.

This will open up a dialog box like the one below.

[image: pedal 2]

Make sure to press "copy". Press CTRL + D or Apple + D (Mac) to transform the rotation again (I used 90 degrees for the transformation).

The basic process of these designs will require you to use basic shapes and transforming them to make your design.

Result

[image: result]

Comment: Hi Andrew, that is exactly what I am trying to create.  Could you explain step one in a little more detail.  Thanks

Comment: Ie is there a geometric way of creating the petal its self.  Halving the circle in at a certain ratio?

Comment: I just used the pen tool to create the pedal based off an image that cockypup commented with. To create your own you will want to create half of the pedal and then copy - paste - reflect to make the object symmetrical. I am not sure what you mean by "Halving the circle in at a certain ratio?"

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I am studying sacred geometry at the moment and a big part of that is creating shapes by intersecting other shapes. So in this example the petal's geometry would have some relation to the main circle.  I will re ask the question to be more clear.